# Converting CSV to Shapefile using pyshp?

Tags: python, shapefile, pyshp

I have a python script which converts csv data to shapefiles. It converts but won't get angle from csv.

Can anyone help me?

The CSV data looks like this:

```
fid_nr;x;y;angle
1;55.474040000;13.020460000;90
2;55.474040000;13.020460000;90
```

And the Python script is:

```
import shapefile as shp
import csv
import os
import sys

fileToOpen = open('test.csv', "rb")

#Set up blank lists for data
fid_nr,x,y,angle=[],[],[],[]

#read data from csv file and store in lists
with open(fileToOpen, 'rb') as csvfile:
    print "File found and will be now converted"
    r = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=";")
    for i,row in enumerate(r):
        print row
        if i > 0: #skip header
            fid_nr.append(row[2])
            x.append(float(row[0]))           
            y.append(float(row[1]))         
            angle.append(row[3])         

#Set up shapefile writer and create empty fields
w = shp.Writer(shp.POINT)
w.autoBalance = 1 #ensures gemoetry and attributes match
w.field("fid_nr","N")
w.field("x","F",10,8)
w.field("y","F",10,8)
w.field("angle","N")    

#loop through the data and write the shapefile
for j,k in enumerate(x):
    w.point(k,y[j]) #write the geometry
    w.record(k,y[j],fid_nr[j],x[j],y[j],angle[j])
#Save shapefile
w.save("Resultat/" + out_file3)
print "Done!"
```

Comment: what do you mean when you say: 'wont get angle from csv'?

Answer (score 4):

You need to ensure that the angle read from the csv is cast as an integer and not a string as it may be at present. To do this change the line: `angle.append(row[3])` to: `angle.append(int(row[3]))`

The second thing to correct is that you have not specified a length of the angle field, which can cause pyshp some problems, so specify a length, in this case `4` should be suitable:

`w.field("angle","N",4)`

These two fixes should allow the data to be written to the angle field of the attribute table.

Answer (score 4):

The problem I think is that you created four attributes

```
w.field("fid_nr","N")
w.field("x","F",10,8)
w.field("y","F",10,8)
w.field("angle","N")
```

but you tried to put six things on it

```
w.record(k,y[j],fid_nr[j],x[j],y[j],angle[j])
```

It should just be

```
w.record(fid_nr[j],x[j],y[j],angle[j])
```

If you want to add k and y[j] then you'd have to create the corresponding attributes/fields.

Comment: the geometry should be fine, your suggestion would also work but the value `k` is an iterator through the list `x`, so will give the correct coordinates.

Comment: Oops. That's rather embarrassing. Thanks for catching that :)

Comment: No worries, I didn't notice the 6 attributes being written into 4 fields :)