# How to create line/polygon shapefiles from geojson using gdal in Python?

Tags: python, gdal, ogr, open-source-gis

I have put this together after reading [How to create polygon shapefile from a list of coordinates using python gdal/ogr?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/217165/how-to-create-polygon-shapefile-from-a-list-of-coordinates-using-python-gdal-ogr), and [How to write Shapely geometries to shapefiles?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/52705/how-to-write-shapely-geometries-to-shapefiles/52708#52708)

I am attempting to read a GeoJSON response and put together 3 different shapefiles; one for each geometric type that may be contained in the response.  Since I'm not very good with gdal/ogr, I figured I'd include a lengthy chunk of the script for evaluation.

**Methods** I'm using to make lines and polygons...

```
def create_line(coords):
    line = ogr.Geometry(ogr.wkbLineString)
    for coord in coords:
        line.AddPoint(float(coord[0], float(coord[1]))
    return line.ExportToWkt()

def create_polygon(coords):
    ring = ogr.Geometry(ogr.wkbLinearRing)
    for coord in coords:
        ring.AddPoint(float(coord[0], float(coord[1]))

    poly = ogr.Geometry(ogr.wkbPolygon)
    poly.AddGeometry(ring)
    return poly.ExportToWkt()
```

**Preparation and Loops** for reading the geojson and building the features...

```
#prep files
outdir = "C:\\Temp"
p_shp = os.path.join(outdir, "point.shp")
l_shp = os.path.join(outdir, "line.shp")
a_shp = os.path.join(outdir, "area.shp")

driver = ogr.GetDriverByName("ESRI Shapefile")
point_data_source = driver.CreateDataSource(os.path.join(outdir, p_shp)
line_data_source = driver.CreateDataSource(os.path.join(outdir, l_shp)
area_data_source = driver.CreateDataSource(os.path.join(outdir, a_shp)

srs = osr.SpatialReference()
srs.ImportFromEPSG(4326)

# Point shapefile setup
p_layer = point_data_source.CreateLayer("point_layer", srs, ogr.wkbPoint)
field_testfield = ogr.FieldDefn("fld_a", ogr.OFTString)
field_testfield.SetWidth(50)
p_layer.CreateField(field_testfield)

# Line shapefile setup
l_layer = line_data_source.CreateLayer("line_layer", srs, ogr.wkbLineString)
field_testfield = ogr.FieldDefn("fld_a", ogr.OFTString)
field_testfield.SetWidth(50)
l_layer.CreateField(field_testfield)

# Area shapefile setup
a_layer = area_data_source.CreateLayer("area_layer", srs, ogr.wkbPolygon)
field_testfield = ogr.FieldDefn("fld_a", ogr.OFTString)
field_testfield.SetWidth(50)
a_layer.CreateField(field_testfield)    

# Do the json reading
for i in jsonObj['features']:
    geo = i.get('geometry')
    geo_type = geo.get('type')
    if geo_type == 'Point':  # If it's a point feature, do this
        [xcoord, ycoord, field_value] = ['', '', 'test']
        coords = geo.get('coordinates')
        xcoord, ycoord = float(coords[0]), float(coords[1])
        # Get properties and build field values here
        if xcoord and ycoord and field_value:
            feature = ogr.Feature(p_layer.GetLayerDefn())
            feature.SetField('fld_a', field_value)

            wkt = "POINT ({} {})".format(xcoord, ycoord)
            point = ogr.CreateGeometryFromWkt(wkt)
            feature.SetGeometry(point)
            p_layer.CreateFeature(feature)
            feature = None
            [xcoord, ycoord, field_value] = ['', '', '']

    elif geo_type == 'LineString':  # Or if it's a line feature, do this
        [line, field_value] = ['', 'test']
        linecoords = geo.get('coordinates')
        line = create_line(linecoords)
        if line and field_value:
            feature = ogr.Feature(l_layer.GetLayerDefn())
            feature.SetField('fld_a', field_value)

            wkt = "LINESTRING ({})".format(line)
            line_feat = ogr.CreateGeometryFromWkt(wkt)
            feature.SetGeometry(line_feat)
            l_layer.CreateFeature(feature)
            feature = None
            [line, field_value] = ['', '']

    elif geo_type == 'Polygon':  # Or if it's a polygon, do this
        [poly, field_value] = ['', 'test']
        polycoords = geo.get('coordinates')
        poly = create_polygon(polycoords)
        if poly and field_value:
            feature = ogr.Feature(a_layer.GetLayerDefn())
            feature.SetField('fld_a', field_value)

            wkt = "POLYGON ({})".format(poly)
            area = ogr.CreateGeometryFromWkt(wkt)
            feature.SetGeometry(area)
            a_layer.CreateFeature(feature)
            feature = None
            [poly, field_value] = ['', '']

    else:
        print('Could not discern geometry')
```

**The Result (UPDATED)**

I'm now using `Fiona` to do this in the way @gene suggested below:

```
for i in jsonObj['features']
geo = i.get('geometry')
geo_type = geo.get('type')
props = i.get('properties')
value_a = props.get('value_a', 'UNK')
value_b = props.get('value_b', 'UNK')
if geo_type == 'Point':
    schema = {'geometry': 'Point', 'properties': {
        'field_a': 'str:50',
        'field_b': 'str:50'}}
    with fiona.open(point_shapefile, 'w', 'ESRI Shapefile', schema) as layer:
        try:
            layer.write({'geometry': json.loads(geo), 'properties': {
                    'field_a': value_a,
                    'field_b': value_b}})
        except TypeError as te:
            print('Problem creating point feature, {}'.format(str(te)))
```

This yields:

```
Problem creating point feature, expected string or buffer
```

I am able to access and print all values out of the json response object `jsonObj`.  However, the `Fiona` layer writing is failing.

Comment: why not use the gdal/ogr geojson driver to read the json in?

Comment: @iant that sounds nice; can you direct me to documentation for doing this in python?  Googling didn't turn up anything on my end and the gdal python cookbook does not seem to contain anything like "Save GeoJSON to Output Layer."

Comment: See https://pcjericks.github.io/py-gdalogr-cookbook/vector_layers.html#get-geometry-from-each-feature-in-a-layer but use GeoJSON instead of ESRI Shapefile in the driver = ogr.GetDriverByName("ESRI Shapefile") line

Comment: When I tried `dataSource = driver.Open(jsonObj, 0)` and then did `for feature in layer: geom = feature.GetGeometryRef() \ print geom` it yielded `RuntimeError: not a string`

Comment: try geom.ExportToWkt()

Comment: @iant nope that doesn't work either, even if i try to coerce it to `str`. Still get the not-a-string error.  Even if I do `for feature in layer: print("{}".format(str(feature)))` it will give me a `not a string`.  Somehow I think it doesn't want to open up `r.json()` (the json response from Requests).  Maybe just tweaking what i have is the best option?

Comment: What is the result of `print {'geometry': json.loads(geo), 'properties': {'field_a': value_a,'field_b': value_b}}) ` ?

Comment: I isolated `json.loads(geo)` and that's where the `TypeError` is coming from.  When I print `geo`, it prints it successfully as `{u'type': u'Point', u'coordinates': [-90.24565, 38.63979]}`  Perhaps it is already being read correctly as a python dict?

Comment: The result should be `{'geometry': {u'type': u'Point', u'coordinates': [-90.24565, 38.63979]}, 'properties': {'field_b': 'UNK', 'field_a': 'UNK'}}`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For creating an OGR geometry from GeoJSON, see [Python GDAL/OGR Cookbook: Create Geometry from GeoJSON](https://pcjericks.github.io/py-gdalogr-cookbook/geometry.html#create-geometry-from-geojson)

```
point = """{"type":"Point","coordinates":[108420.33,753808.59]}"""
line = """{ "type": "LineString", "coordinates": [ [100.0, 0.0], [101.0, 1.0] ]}"""
poly = """{ "type": "Polygon","coordinates": [[ [100.0, 0.0], [101.0, 0.0], [101.0, 1.0], [100.0, 1.0], [100.0, 0.0] ],[ [100.2, 0.2], [100.8, 0.2], [100.8, 0.8], [100.2, 0.8], [100.2, 0.2] ]]}"""
from osgeo import ogr
pointogr = ogr.CreateGeometryFromJson(point)
lineogr = ogr.CreateGeometryFromJson(line)
polyogr = ogr.CreateGeometryFromJson(poly)
```

After that

```
driver = ogr.GetDriverByName('ESRI Shapefile')
ds = driver.CreateDataSource('line.shp')
layer = ds.CreateLayer('line', geom_type=ogr.wkbLineString)
field_testfield = ogr.FieldDefn("fld_a", ogr.OFTString)
field_testfield.SetWidth(50)
layer.CreateField(field_testfield)
feature = ogr.Feature(layer.GetLayerDefn())
feature.SetField("fld_a",'test')
feature.SetGeometry(lineogr)
layer.CreateFeature(feature)
feature = None
ds = None
```

But it is easier with [Fiona](http://toblerity.github.com/fiona/manual.html) (another OGR Python bindings)

```
import fiona
import json
# shapefile schema
schema = {'geometry': 'LineString','properties': {'fld_a': 'str:50'}}
with fiona.open('line2.shp', 'w', 'ESRI Shapefile', schema) as layer:
      layer.write({'geometry': json.loads(line), 'properties': {'fld_a': 'test'}})

schema = {'geometry': 'Point','properties': {'fld_a': 'str:50'}}
with fiona.open('point.shp', 'w', 'ESRI Shapefile', schema) as layer:
      layer.write({'geometry': json.loads(point), 'properties': {'fld_a': 'test'}})

schema = {'geometry': 'Polygon','properties': {'fld_a': 'str:50'}}
with fiona.open('polygon.shp', 'w', 'ESRI Shapefile', schema) as layer:
      layer.write({'geometry': json.loads(poly), 'properties': {'fld_a': 'test'}})
```

Comment: Thanks @gene - I like the Fiona way and am working on it - but when you write `json.loads(line)` do you actually mean `json.loads(lineogr)`?

Comment: No, Fiona uses the GeoJSON format and  dictionaries. `json.loads(line)`transform the string to a Python dictionary

Comment: Thanks gene, I've edited the results section of my original post, see the update for new errors using the Fiona approach.  I'm sure I'm making a simple logical error somewhere but can't discern it.

Comment: Now I have the script successfully writing into a file, but it only writes one row and overwrites the file over and over.  Do you suggest creating the shapefile container in a separate step and then opening it using `'a'` flag or is there a more elegant solution?

Comment: I does not understand your problem. No problem for me: one geometry = one shapefile

Comment: I got it.  I'm iterating over a json response, not casting a single geometry.  When I nested the `for` loop inside of the `with fiona.open()` call, everything worked.  Thanks again gene!