# Add layer to map in qgis3 via a python script

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-3

I'm trying convert my old plugin to QGIS3 and one part is to create a shapefile, and afterwards load it to the Layer menu like this:

```
from qgis.core import QgsVectorLayer, QgsProject
layer = QgsVectorLayer('c:/dev/test.shp', 'test', "ogr")
print(layer.isValid())
QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(layer)
```

The python console returns True and the Layer appears in the layer list, hence I can't add features to it when I have toggled editing:

[image]

However, if I remove the layer from layer list and add the layer with the same code in the Python console I have no problem with adding a feature.

Any suggestions for what I can try?

Comment: Works fine for me, perhaps an issue with the build you are using (I tested this with `QGIS 33ca8fcb69`)? Is this the latest build you are using?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved the problem, I believe that the layer was loaded without fields in some way. It was wired though, it had an 'ID' column when I checked in the Attribute table, but somehow I believe that it had something todo with error anyway. When I changed the layer creation method (by the help of [the code in this question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/217165/how-to-create-polygon-shapefile-from-a-list-of-coordinates-using-python-gdal-ogr)) the layer was loaded correctly from the plugin.