# Making polygon shapefile from unsorted point shapefile?

Tags: qgis, python, gdal, geometry, ogr

I have a point Shapefile with unsorted feature ID's (FID). I want to convert the same point file into polygon Shapefile by using python gdal/ogr. I got the help from [link1](https://pcjericks.github.io/py-gdalogr-cookbook/geometry.html#create-a-polygon) and [link2](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/217165/how-to-create-polygon-shapefile-from-a-list-of-coordinates-using-python-gdal-ogr). I'm able to make polygon shapefile successfully but because of my unsorted point Shapefile the output of polygon shapefile is irregular (not as expected). Expected polygon shapefile is ring/polygon/box around points .[image: Point Shapefile][image: Point shapefile with zoom]

[image: Polygon Shapefile][image: POlygon Shapefile with Zoom].
Is there any way to sort point shapes as right to left or left to right before making polygon Shapefile?

Comment: The definition of a polygon asserts that the vertex list is ordered. Randomly organized points can't be reliably sorted to form polygons. You can generate a convex hull, or it's sibling, a concave hull, but points *within* the polygon will be dropped.

Comment: Ya convex hull drops the intermediate points. But I want to do more precisely.

Comment: Right. So you have an impossible task, or at least an *NP-Complete* one.

Answer (score 1):

My idea is to order point coordinates by its longitude and latitude in this way:

1. Sort by longitude, in for loop iterate over the coordinates while longitude ascends;
2. Then iterate while latitude descends;
3. etc...

Then merge lists with coordinates and create polygon.

Not pretend this is the most elegant solution, maybe you send your data so I will test my idea

Comment: Your idea is good but  I had more than one lakh random points. How I can sort ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37111840/8129993 answer about sorting coordinates. My idea is to create lists first (with ascending\descending longitude\latitude) and sort coordinates inside

Comment: I have tried, The sorting of coordinates is good for  the points in a path but my points are around the box.